# How to disable Rating Component onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to stop the user from voting more than once, by disabling the Rating component on click. I've tried `using onClick={() =>  this.disabled=true`} but that's giving me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'disabled')
at onClick".

```
 function Rating(props) {
      const [activeValue, setActiveValue] = useState(0);
    
      return (
        <MDBRating
          // className="rating-active-example"
          active={activeValue} // Changes how many stars are active
          setActive={setActiveValue}
        >
          <MDBRatingElement
            title="Terrible"
            itemId={1}
            icon="star"
            onClick={() => addRating(props.id, 1)}
          />
          <MDBRatingElement
            title="Poor"
            itemId={2}
            icon="star"
            onClick={() => addRating(props.id, 2)}
          />
          <MDBRatingElement
            title="OK"
            itemId={3}
            icon="star"
            onClick={() => addRating(props.id, 3)}
          />
          <MDBRatingElement
            title="Good"
            itemId={4}
            icon="star"
            onClick={() => addRating(props.id, 4)}
          />
          <MDBRatingElement
            title="Excellent"
            itemId={5}
            icon="star"
            onClick={() => addRating(props.id, 5)}
          />
        </MDBRating>
```

Edit:

I put a clickHandler and state for the clicks. I need to stop updating the active stars onClick. Do I need to use a useEffect or something? As conditonal is not working.

```
  var [isNotClicked, setIsNotClicked] = useState(true);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setIsNotClicked = false;
    console.log(setIsNotClicked);
  };
  return (
    <MDBRating?
      active={activeValue} // Changes how many stars are active
      onClick={clickHandler}
      setActive={setIsNotClicked ? setActiveValue : null }
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is probably not what you thought what it is inside a functional component. You can keep track of which element is clicked more than once using state variable. Or even better, you can do that inside the implementation of `MDBRatingElement` or `MDBRating`

```
onClick={() => {
 // check if already clicked
 if(!alreadyClicked) {props.onClick()} 
}}
```